# Align code inside the vertical line after formatting

Tags: intellij-idea, format

When I format the code in intellij with `Alt + L` the code doesn't align to go inside the vertical line in intellij.

Here is an example what I mean: 
[image]

This array goes outside the vertical line, there where **"test5"** starts. When I format it, it will not be broken and go to a new line like this:

[image]

How can I set it in so it will format the code inside the line?

I googled it but what i found was only "how to remove the vertical line"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File | Settings | Editor | Code Style | Java, Wrapping and Braces, set the relevant options to **Wrap if long**:

[image: wrap]